# ValueError: Expected x_max for bbox (0.65, 0.51, 1.12, 0.64, 3) to be in the range [0.0, 1.0], got 1.1234809015877545

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, bounding-box, albumentations

I want to apply data augmentations from PyTorch's Albumentations to images with bounding boxes.

When I apply the HorizontalFlip Transformation, I receive this error `ValueError: Expected x_max for bbox (0.6505353259854019, 0.517013871576637, 1.1234809015877545, 0.6447916687466204, 3) to be in the range [0.0, 1.0], got 1.1234809015877545.`

I use the following code

```
A.Compose([
           A.HorizontalFlip(p=1),
           ToTensorV2(p=1.0)],
           p=1.0,     
           bbox_params=A.BboxParams(format='coco',min_area=0, min_visibility=0,label_fields=['labels'])
                  )
```

When I apply the Cutout transformation, I do not have any error regarding the bounding boxes

```
A.Compose([
          A.Cutout(num_holes=10, max_h_size=32, max_w_size=32, fill_value=0, p=0.5),
          ToTensorV2(p=1.0)],
          p=1.0,       
          bbox_params=A.BboxParams(format='coco',min_area=0, min_visibility=0,label_fields=['labels'])
                  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bounding box exceeded the image since after the transformation it ends up being larger than the image size. Check carefully the dimensions of the bounding box.

Comment: could you please tell me how you solved the issue? or what exactly do I need to check?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Be carreful of the format of your dataset, maybe you passed Pascal_VOC format instead of coco.
https://albumentations.ai/docs/getting_started/bounding_boxes_augmentation/

Answer (score 1):

The reason maybe is you use opencv to read image, not PIL.Image.
Opencv read image is: H*W*C.
PIL.Image read image is: W*H*C.
And Albumentations need the input is :W*H*C.